# TestNG - how to share same browser session between two methods?

Tags: testng, browser-session

I am writing TestNG code for the below scenario and do not know how to share browser session between two methods: 
1. Creating a data driven testNG suite to login using 10 different usernames
I need to write two methods and both methods should share the same browser session. Any idea how to share browser session between two test methods using TestNG?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite get why you would like to share browser session.
UI test methods should be run in the own independent browser.
In case you insist, you could use @BeforeClass of TestNG and have driver set up done in @BeforeClass method. Now both of your methods should be either in this class or class with extends the set up class. Confused? This might help -

```
public class TestCase {

  @BeforeClass
  public void setup() {
    // Set up driver here

  @BeforeClass
  public void tearDown() {
    // kill driver here
  }
```

}

And you test class here -

```
public class MyHorribleClassWhichUsesSameBrowserForMultipleTests extends TestCase{

  @Test
  public void method1() {
    // test code here

  @Test
  public void method2() {
    // test code here
  }
}
```

Here both test methods would be using same browser one after another.

Comment: Is there not a parameter in @WebTest like "keepBrowserOpen" or "OpenNewSession" (bool) ?